# Google Chrome Not Rendering Image Correctly in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

As can be seen in the image here with, yellow O in  the google not rendering correctly. Similar image rendering issue happen with other sites also.

How do I further debug this  or solve this ?

[image]